# Query string update breaks setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, setstate

I'm updating my url when i select a date from my date picker. To update just the date query in the url, i'm doing a `history.replace` and to set selected value to my state i'm doing a `setState`. But i'm facing an issue where my url gets updated (just the query i need) but the state won't get updated. Here is my code

```
    handleStartDate = date => {

        this.setState({
            startDate: date
        });
        var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
        var day = date.getUTCDate();
        var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
        var newsStartDate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;

        const query = new URLSearchParams(this.props.history.location.search);
        query.set("filterInitDate", newsStartDate);
        this.props.history.replace({
            search: query.toString()
        });

};
```

my url is like below

```
http://localhost:3000/transactions?page=1&limit=15&filter=%27%27&filterInitDate=2019%2F11%2F2&filterEndDate=2019%2F11%2F18
```

I'm able to update `filterInitDate` with this function but only issue i'm facing is state `startDate` won't get updated using setState. What can be the reason for this?

My date picker

```
<DatePicker
     className="form-control"
     customInput={<ExampleCustomInput pickerType="from" />}
     selected={this.state.startDate}
     onChange={this.handleStartDate}
     adjustDateOnChange
     dateFormat="dd / MM / yyyy"
/>
```

if i comment out the below code, my state will get updated but then the url won't get updated.

```
this.props.history.replace({
            search: query.toString()
        });
```

Comment: it's hard to find out what's happening in your case without example. Is it possible to share some repl/sandbox with this issue reproduced?

Comment: Why are you modifying `this.props.history`? Are you trying to update the state?

Comment: I'm calling a API on componentDidMount. I'm getting the parameter values from the url. So i need to update my url ,to do that i'm using history.update

Comment: But where is `props.history` comming from? Is it an object with methods? Could you share how is your state?

Answer (score 0):

```
var newSearchParams = updateQueryStringParameter(props.history.location.search, "timeStart", startDate);

props.history.push(newSearchParams);
```

and then update your state with setState.

If Your component rendering first time , pass default value  to state from queryParam.

```
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
    let re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
    let separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
    if (uri.match(re))
        return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
    else
        return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
}
```